# Make form fields required only if a file is not attached/uplodad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a page with a job application form where users can fill in their contact info, and then either upload a resume document, or fill out the rest of the form.

The problem is, I need to make certain fields required only if there is no resume attached. Splitting it into separate forms is not an option.

Is there a way to use javascript to require certain fields only when there is no resume attached?

Or alternatively, to automatically fill in the required fields with "See Resume" when a user attaches the resume file?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a `change` handler to the file input element and update the required fields like so:

```
$('#myFileInput').change(function() {
   $('.myRequiredField').val("See Resume");
});
```

Comment: There is a typo `$j` should be either `$` or `jQuery`

Comment: @Vadim Fixed, sorry.  I'm used to using that alias in a couple of my projects that have to co-exist with Prototype.